# Can I conclude $s$ is a submersion from these data?

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Let $M$ and $N$ be smooth manifolds ($C^\infty$). Let $s\in C^\infty(M, N)$ and $u\in C^\infty(N, M)$ be maps satisfying:

- $u$ is an embedding;
- $s\circ u=\textrm{id}_N$;
- $(u\circ s)^2=u\circ s$.

Using this data can I conclude $s$ is a submersion?

Thanks.

Comment: Your last equation is a corollary of the second, so can only hold less data. But from the second, yes, you can conclude what you want. (You don't even need the first fact; actually, if $M$ is compact, the first fact follows automatically from the second.) Try it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not in general. Let $N = \mathbb{R}, M = \mathbb{R}^2$ and consider the following maps:

$$ u(x) = (x,0), \,\,\, s(x,y) = x(y+1). $$

The map $u$ is an embedding whose image is the $x$-axis. The map $s$ is a smooth retract onto the $x$-axis and like Mike Miller noted, the third condition follows from the second condition. Geometrically, $u \circ s$ sends points on the hyperbola $x(y+1) = \varepsilon$ (or $y = \frac{\varepsilon}{x} - 1$) to their unique intersection $(\varepsilon, 0)$ with the $x$-axis. However, the map $s$ is clearly not a smooth submersion since the preimage $s^{-1}(0)$ is a degenerate hyperbola which is not a smooth manifold (or alternatively, $ds|_{(0,-1)} = 0$).

However, since the first condition implies that $ds_p$ must be onto for all $p \in \mathrm{Im}(u)$ and since being onto is an open condition, you can conclude that there exists an open neighborhood $U$ of $\mathrm{Im}(u)$ in $M$ such that $s|_U$ is a submersion.

Comment: Oh, yeah, my comment is totally false. Whoops!

Comment: Don't worry. BTW, I think that the second condition implies the first (and the third) even if $M$ is not compact (although less trivially) since the image of a smooth retract must be an embedded submanifold.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Just threw down some quick thoughts; sometimes those are garbage. :)

Comment: Thanks. The fact that $s$ is ``locally a submersion'' would be enough to conclude $\{(x, y)\in M\times M: s(x)=t(y)\}$ is a smooth manifold (where $t:M\longrightarrow N$ is a smooth map)?

Comment: No. If you take $t(x,y) \equiv 0$ in my example above, you will get that the fiber product is identified with $s^{-1}(0)$. You can restrict $t$ and $s$ to $U$ and then take their fibered product - this will be a smooth manifold.